# call wake_up_interruptible() on a wait queue which is not used by any process to sleep

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, wait

I have a situation where i have to call  `wake_up_interruptible()` on a wait queue, which may not holding any process to sleep. Is it ok to call `wake_up_interruptible()` on an unused wait queue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as the queue is initialized you are fine.